# Blender 2.49b crashes when right-clicking to select an object

Tags: mesh, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

After updating my Windows 10 tonight, I'm now having a problem in Blender version 2.49b where every time I try to right-click an object to select it, Blender instantly crashes and closes.

1 - Yes, I have to use this version of Blender. It's the only version that can import/export nif files for Skyrim modding.

2 - No, my object does not use subsurfing. No, I am not trying to animate or make a movie. It's just a very simple, low-poly object.

3 - The issue does not occur for a new file with 1 starter cube, but as soon as I add another object and try to select either of the 2 objects, the crash occurs.

4 - If I press A to select all, the crash does not occur. The problem only happens when trying to select an individual object via right-click.

5 - I have an Intel graphics driver, but I just updated it, and updating did not fix the problem.

Any help you guys could give would be appreciated. I went through all of the google pages on this topic, and none of them have advice for my version of Blender.

(NOTE: This is NOT a duplicate! I have to use an old version of Blender that no one seems to have given existing advice for. I have already gone through all the similar questions on this site, and none of them have helped. )

Comment: i) Roll back your windows version (or get some old box with XP)  ii) Update  script iii) Don't right click select... may all be quicker in the long run than coaxing > 10yo software to run on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Runnig such an old version of Blender on a modern version of windows can lead to incompatibilities such as you are experiencing - the old versions were obviously developed way before Windows 10 was even imagined and there are all kinds of reasons why newer Windows could expose a bug that’s been dormant and undiscovered in the old Blender code.

Probably the best way forward is to run against an older version of the operating system that doesn’t experience the problem. If you don’t have the physical hardware to run such a system you can run it as a ‘virtual’ computer using VM tools such as VirtualBox. I’ve had great success running older versions of Blender on VirtualBox running Linux (which is free to install if you can’t get Windows XP) - so I currently have a Windows 10 laptop running Blender 2.79.6 and Blender 2.8 and use a Linux VM (in VirtualBox) to run earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free add-on for this, on [**Github**](https://github.com/niftools/blender_nif_plugin). See if it works with Blender 2.79b, downloaded as a .zip file, so that you don't have to install it. If it does work, enjoy this latest version of Blender.